# Attempt of the access to ViewBag properties closes my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't understand why my app crashes. This is my action in a controller:

```
public ActionResult AttachmentsPartial(Guid processId)
{
    var staff = GetCurrentStaff();
    var process = Db.Processes.Include(nameof(Stages)).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == processId);

    if (process != null && staff != null)
    {
        var stages = process.Stages.ToList();
        ViewBag.Stages = stages;
        var files = new List<AttachmentViewModel<Guid>>();

        foreach (var stage in stages)
        {
            //***Some code***
            files.AddRange(items);
        }

        return PartialView("_AttachmentsPartial", files);
    }

    return PartialView("_AttachmentsPartial");
}
```

And my view:

```
@model List<AttachmentViewModel<Guid>>

@using PM.Models;
@using PM.Resources.Strings;
@using PM.Utils;

@{
    List<Stages> stages = ViewBag.Stages; // This crashes here
}
```

Earlier, it crashes with `StackOverflowException` but it outputs a nothing now, just finish app.
I try to debug this code and it crashes when I try to get access to the `ViewBag.Stages`. Even if I try to make it in debugger only.

Comment: You would need to cast it (`ViewBag` is dynamic) - `List<Stages> stages = ViewBag.Stages as List<Stages>` and you would need to test for `null` since you controller only sets it in the `if` block.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it doesn't require a casting and if it is `null` then this code must make `stages` equals `null` only, doesn't crash app. But it isn't `null` because I checked it in my controller.

Comment: have you tried catching the error in the Application_Error() in Global.asax?

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis, no, I haven't. I even didn't know about it)

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis, it doesn't output any errors.

Comment: bump Stephen Muecke's comment ... needs a cast, I think something like (List<Stages>)ViewBag.Stages

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I often use to find errors when loading partials etc that just seem to dump out with no trace.

In Global.asax.cs create:

```
 protected void Application_Error()
 {
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    HttpException ex = exception as HttpException;

    var test = ex.GetHttpCode();
}
```

I just put a breakpoint on the exception and hover over it when it throws. It usually tells me what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You try assign array to list?

```
List<Stages> stages = ViewBag.Stages;
```

Make it

```
Stages[] stages = ViewBag.Stages;
```

Comment: No) I copied old source. Just I tried to switch it to an array but it still didn't work.